# i am getting the error in flutter with firebase when i try to use it in web it runs without error but when try it to run in android it shows error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

this is my error on sstart running flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X689 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/om.example.tri( 8942): Compiler allocated 4303KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:56884/3eZE98OlI34=/ws
I/FirebaseApp( 8942): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
E/ion     ( 8942): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

this is my pubspec file .i have recently updated all packages to latest version

```
name: trip
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  # firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  video_player: ^2.7.0
  get: ^4.6.5
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.3
  http: ^1.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.5
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1

  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  visibility_detector: 0.4.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  flutter_reorderable_grid_view: ^4.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  file_picker: ^5.3.3
  path: ^1.8.3

 
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
    # - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

i am using the dart version 3.0.6
i am  also getting some other errors. these errors are given below
is these errors are due to device or due to code

my complete project is this https://github.com/rajcrack/trip

```
E/ion     ( 8942): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
I/FirebaseAuth( 8942): Logging in as rprp9297@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  ( 8942): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out( 8942): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  ( 8942): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out( 8942): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out( 8942): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System  ( 8942): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out( 8942): [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
```